# Gc logs not printing

Tags: java, java-8, garbage-collection, jboss6.x

I pass the below value to jvms hosted on Jboss :

```
                            <option value="-XX:+PrintGCDetails"/>
                           <option value="-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"/>
                           <option value="-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps"/>
                           <option value="-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation"/>
                           <option value="-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=50"/>
                           <option value="-XX:GCLogFileSize=50M"/>
                           <option value="-Xloggc:=/some/path/gc-%t.log"/>
```

But I dont' see any files with gc* under /some/path/ location.

I use JDK 8

Answer (score 0):

The last option looks wrong, the `=` character does not belong there, so it should be:

```
                       <option value="-Xloggc:/some/path/gc-%t.log"/>
```

Please note that the option dependes on the JDK/JRE version:

- JDK up to version 8: `-Xloggc:LOG_FILE_PATH`
- JDK since version 9: `-Xlog:gc:LOG_FILE_PATH`, see https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158